# In DataAdapter Why we use Update SQL Statement when we manually have to Change Value in a Column

Tags: c#, ado.net

I am new to DataAdapter. So please bear with me.

Why is the Update `SqlCommand` and UPDATE SQL statement required and Value given to the Update command (using parameters) when we mandatorily have to change the value in the datatable by actually assigning it. Which means **only** providing the Update SQL does not work?

We have to do this and only then the database gets updated when we do `DataAdapter.Update()`?

```
    DataRow categoryRow = categoryTable.Rows[0];
    categoryRow["CategoryName"] = "New Beverages";
```

Because like here the column value of `Rows[0]` is changed manually. But, if there were 10 rows in the `DataTable` and we want to change values in more than 1 row based on the UPDATE SQL statement condition.

This is the full code which works, but i dont understand the use of having a UPDATE Sqlcommand when the actual work is done by manually changing the value in the column of a specific row.

```
private static void AdapterUpdate(string connectionString)
{
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        SqlDataAdapter dataAdpater = new SqlDataAdapter(
          "SELECT CategoryID, CategoryName FROM Categories",
          connection);

        dataAdpater.UpdateCommand = new SqlCommand(
           "UPDATE Categories SET CategoryName = @CategoryName " +
           "WHERE CategoryID = @CategoryID", connection);

        dataAdpater.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add(
           "@CategoryName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 15, "CategoryName");

        SqlParameter parameter = dataAdpater.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add(
          "@CategoryID", SqlDbType.Int);
        parameter.SourceColumn = "CategoryID";
        parameter.SourceVersion = DataRowVersion.Original;

        DataTable categoryTable = new DataTable();
        dataAdpater.Fill(categoryTable);

        DataRow categoryRow = categoryTable.Rows[0];
        categoryRow["CategoryName"] = "New Beverages";

        dataAdpater.Update(categoryTable);

        Console.WriteLine("Rows after update.");
        foreach (DataRow row in categoryTable.Rows)
        {
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", row[0], row[1]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is for other people who face the same doubt.

Just figured out...

The Update SQL is for the update in Database  and it will update the values given/updated in the DataTable column. Also only those columns will be updated in the Database which are mentioned in the Update SQL statement SET Columns. So if you have updated a value in a DataTable column, but it is not one of the SET columns of the UPDATE SQL, then that value is not updated to the Database.

So the SQL is also required along with the updated Datatable column values.

I hope i am clear :)